# Looking for Query for NEXT_DAY for Oracle to SQL server 2012 migration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express, dateadd

Looking for code in SQL SERVER 2012 to find out Next occurrence of 'WEDNESDAY' for all ORDERDATEs from ORDERS Table. I came up with the following, but it just gives the Orderdate + 7 days. Kindly help me on this.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DD,7, CONVERT(Datetime, OrderDate, 101))
FROM Orders
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,OrderDate) = 'Wednesday' 
       THEN DATEADD(DAY,7,OrderDate)
       ELSE DATEADD(DAY,(18-(@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(WEEKDAY,OrderDate)))%7,OrderDate)
       END
FROM Orders
```

Comment: But this query is returning '04/01/2009' (mm/dd/yyyy) even though the date is past 1st april. Means - even though the date is 2,3,4 of that week it is returning '04/01/2009' http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2009

Comment: Now I am getting it right. Thank you. But when the date itself is '04/01/2009' its returning the same date. But am looking for the next occurrence, So it should be returning me '04/08/2009' for '04/01/2009'

Comment: @PrincessS Well, now this is an ugly query, but I think it works.

Comment: @PrincessS yup, there was a missing `END` there (pretyy easy to spot, though)

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your patience and help. I am very much new to SQL. Just started learning myself, haven't came across CASE yet.